# How to get text from text box using protractor for Angular 7 application

Tags: node.js, protractor

```
**var object = element(by.xpath(Locator));
  expect(object.isPresent()).toEqual(true);
  var appText = object.getText();
  appText.then(async function(text){
       console.log("appliation text: ",text);
  }**
```

I have mentioned above the code which I'm trying to execute. But it is returning empty value.

Comment: Please, elaborate more about the problem, what you are trying to achieve, e.g what are the value assigned to Locator, element variables/function.

Comment: Actually I found the solutions. I'm trying to get the value from the text box using protractor. the variable object will return the web element then I'm trying to execute getText() method to get the textbox value.
Answer:
Instead of using "var appText = object.getText();" you can use "var appText = await object.getAttribute('value');"

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the object to be present but not displayed or not contains value in it.

```
  var object = element(by.xpath(Locator));
  expect(object.getText()).trimLeft().trimRight()).toNotEqual('');
  var appText = object.getText();
  appText.then(async function(text){
  console.log("appliation text: ",text);
  }
```